# Как шифровать и дешифровать файл алгоритмом Blowfish в java?

Tags: blowfish, криптография, java, шифрование

Всем привет. Нужно зашифровать и расшифровать файл Blowfish(ем). Я в этом деле новичек. Попробовал сделать. Получилось,что файл шифруется,но не рассшифровывается. Помогите понять в чем проблема. Заранее спасибо.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;

public class Blowfish {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String key = "squirrel123";

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("original.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("encrypted.txt");
        encrypt(key, fis, fos);

        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("encrypted.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream("decrypted.txt");
        decrypt(key, fis2, fos2);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void encrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os)
        throws Throwable {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void decrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os)
        throws Throwable {
    encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, is, os);
}

public static void encryptOrDecrypt(String key, int mode, InputStream is,
        OutputStream os) throws Throwable {

    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
    keyGenerator.init(128);
    Key secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CFB/NoPadding");

    if (mode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, cipher);
        doCopy(cis, os);
    } else if (mode == Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE) {

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(os, cipher);
        doCopy(is, cos);
    }
}

public static void doCopy(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
        throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
    int numBytes;
    while ((numBytes = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        os.write(bytes, 0, numBytes);
    }
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметр `key` не используется, получается, что вы шифруете с одним ключом, а пытаетесь дешифровать с другим:

```
Key secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

Comment: Т.е это строка вообще не нужна
    Key secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

Comment: При шифровании вы генерируете случайный ключ через `generateKey()`, при дешифровке делаете то же самое, то есть генерируете опять случайный ключ. Как нетрудно догадаться ключ которым вы шифруете и ключ которым вы дешифруете должны быть идентичны. Я просто вас пытаюсь подвигнуть к самостоятельному решению проблемы: вам надо на основе заданной строки сгенерировать ключ один раз или же сгенерировать случайный ключ один раз и передавать при шифровке и дешифровке.

Comment: Спасибо,вот теперь понял.